# Break for case statement

Tags: bash, case-statement

How can I prevent to run `*)` (with `echo "Other"`) in follow code?

I want when `$a` is equal 18 just echo "A". Now echo "A" and "Other"

```
case "$a" in

[17-20])  
    echo "A"
    ;;
*) echo "Other"
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: Cannot duplicate, since "A" is not printed. Not surprising, since that's not how character ranges work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
case "$a" in
  1[789])      # range 17-19
    echo "A"
    ;;
  20)          # only 20
    echo "A"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Other"
    ;;
esac
```

**Shorter version:**

```
case "$a" in
  1[7-9]|20)      # range 17-19 and 20
    echo "A"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Other"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

`case` doesn't know about *ranges* and only takes *patterns*.

Instead you could use `if ... else`.

```
if ((a>=17 && a<=20)); then
  echo "A"
else
  echo "Other"
fi
```